# Can't start docker daemon—invalid image

Tags: docker, coreos

I am unable to start `docker daemon`. When I try I get a bunch of errors saying

```
invalid image sha256:{some sha here}, failed to verify image: sha256{some sha here}
```

and then one line that says

```
Error starting daemon: layer does not exist
```

I suspect the images are corrupted or something—there was an issue the last time this server was shut down. I don't mind removing the images, but I can't find any way to do that without getting docker started. I was hoping there was some sort of `--skip verify` argument, but I can't find anything like that.

How can I get docker started?

OS is CoreOS 1010.5.0.

Answer (score 5):

[I found this script](https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/620339f166984540f15aadef2348646eee9a5b42/contrib/nuke-graph-directory.sh) on the Docker GitHub page that will safely delete files in `/var/lib/docker`. Running that wiped out all the corrupted images and I was able to successfully start `docker daemon`.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me, also I should run service docker stop before this (otherwise some files locked)